# Error in Tensorflow: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask-rcnn

I am trying to use Mask RCNN on python 3.6.8 and getting the following error:

```
tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py:553 make_tensor_proto
        "supported type." % (type(values), values))

    TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("mrcnn_detection/DenseToDenseSetOperation:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("mrcnn_detection/DenseToDenseSetOperation:1", shape=(None,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("mrcnn_detection/DenseToDenseSetOperation:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Can someone please help? This is my first time using tensorflow. Thanks!

I have no idea what to do, searching for answers did not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.